# iOS App crash when inserting thousands of data with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

Actually, I have implemented background sync call which stores data in a local database using CoreData. I am getting thousands of records for that, but the app crashes after some time and giving the error

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code 1.

Maybe it happened due to `NSManagedObjectContext`, not sure. Here is my code:

```
-(void)RestClient:(RestClient *)client didCompleteWithSuccess:(id)responseObject withLastModifiedDate:(NSString *)lastModifiedDate{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

    @try {

        if(responseObject!=nil){

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            if (!error) {

                int totalrecords = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"records"] intValue];

                if(totalrecords>0){
                    NSManagedObjectContext * manageObjContext = [Common getBkgManagedObjectContext];
                    NSArray* rows = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"rows"];

                    for(NSString* email in rows){
                        [NotifyEmails insertIntoNotifyEmails:email withManagedObjectContext:manageObjContext];
                    }

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    if (![manageObjContext save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Data couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception in rest response");
        NSLog(@"Error :: %@",exception);
    }@finally {
        [self finishOperation];
    }

});
}
```

**The NsmanagedObjectContext function :**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getBkgManagedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *manageObjCtx;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [(EMAINTAINAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        manageObjCtx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [manageObjCtx setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    return manageObjCtx;

}
```

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code 1 means you are trying to access something which is null/nil. So enable Zombies to figure out the issue. BTW You should be performing changes to managed objects in managedObject context using `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` these API's will ensure that you end up accessing managed object context in a thread safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

`ManagedObjectContext` are not thread safe.  It is vital to know for each context which thread it want to be run on. A context that was created with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` comes bundled with a private thread that you can ONLY access with `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` (in other words the queue is PRIVATE).  It is not safe to access the context on any other thread - even a background thread.  The context is not attached to the thread that it was created on (as you seem to be assuming it will be), that was the behavior of `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` which is now deprecated.